# Is it okay to ask for confirmation of a suspected bug?

Tags: discussion

The bug is on the phone. Yes I know there are many. I won't go into the nature of the bug, but I am pretty sure it is one. It is however not registered on lauchpad (yet).I Also checked with ppl on the touch irc. Nothing definite there although someone said he had seen it. So its vague.

I could just submit it on LP and see what happens. But the bug could be caused by faulty hardware. It seems usefull to check with AU users if this bug can be confirmed or replicated, before putting in the effort of an LP submit.

However, one could argue that AU is not for that really. It is not a bug testing site. I suspect someone will close my topic on the grounds that if its a suspected bug, I should just go to LP.

So my question is: could I ask that question? :)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the best way to track bugs and see if people can replicate the behavior is in LaunchPad, since it's a bug **tracker** were several people can suscribe themself to it. So no, bugs or suspecting bugs are off-topic in AskUbuntu. What is a bug?

> A software bug is an error or fault in a computer program which makes it fail to work as it's supposed to. This could be as simple as failing to work at all, or as complicated as a subtly incorrect result. Nevertheless, we really want to eliminate software bugs, as they make programs less useful.
>
> Some things aren't bugs, but are missing features that should be reasonably included. Missing features shouldn't be reported as bugs, instead FeatureSpecifications should be written for them. There isn't a bright line that you can draw between bugs and missing features, but here's a guideline: **if it's a problem that would have many details to address, it's likely to be a feature**. For example, the inability to write files safely to a modern OS X partition is a missing feature. The inability to write files safely to a ReiserFS partition would be a bug.
>
> A software bug is an error, flaw, failure, or fault in a computer program or system that produces an incorrect or unexpected result, or causes it to behave in unintended ways. Most bugs arise from mistakes and errors made by people in either a program's source code or its design, or in frameworks and operating systems used by such programs, and a few are caused by compilers producing incorrect code. A program that contains a large number of bugs, and/or bugs that seriously interfere with its functionality, is said to be buggy. Reports detailing bugs in a program are commonly known as bug reports, defect reports, fault reports, problem reports, trouble reports, change requests, and so forth.
>
> Bugs trigger errors that can in turn have a wide variety of ripple effects, with varying levels of inconvenience to the user of the program. Some bugs have only a subtle effect on the program's functionality, and may thus lie undetected for a long time. More serious bugs may cause the program to crash or freeze. Others qualify as security bugs and might for example enable a malicious user to bypass access controls in order to obtain unauthorized privileges.

**TL;dr:** Bugs are errors that are always reproducible under certain circumstances and behaviors unexpected of the piece of software.

Comment: You could ask in [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) though.

Comment: mhm I agree with the supplied anwers in themselves. But they are anwering my question with the assumption that we know for a fact that it's a bug. The definition Braiam supplies is limited to that. That wasn't my question exactly:
I want to find out whether we are (with reasonable certainty) dealing with a bug or not. If I get a yes on that, sure I will do an LP submit. And with that, the process of bug tracking starts.

Comment: The practical reason in this case I thought of putting a line in the water on AU is because 1) I will be hitting a much larger target audience (compared to irc or AU chat). 2) The suspected bug does not require intricate configs by other users. I just want a bunch of ppl saying yes I see that happening.

Still, this is now a genuine meta discussion as I am atm preparing to submit the bug. Still like to hear if my comment changed anyones mind :)

Comment: For that fact I told you "what **is** a bug" and "what **is not** a bug". If it's reproducible and isn't an expected behavior = bug. If it's that you really don't know what you are doing then is a question. Also, you can ask in chat a Seth pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

While I agree with Braiam's answer here, I will make a note:  Feature requests and help with bugs are not on topic here on Ask Ubuntu.  If you want to ask someone to try and confirm a bug, file the bug on Launchpad, don't ask people here to confirm if a bug exists.  Anything bug related is off-topic.